# How should I discuss my wife's due date?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

How do I tell people when my wife's due date is? I usually say something like "el bebé se debe nacer el cuatro de junio" but I don't know if that's the correct way to say it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost, but "nacer" is not reflexive, so it's:

> El bebé debe nacer el cuatro de junio.

Also people use "esperar" (expect):

> Lo esperamos (el bebé) para el cuatro de junio.

EDIT: As Laura says, another way is:

> Mi mujer sale de cuentas el cuatro de junio.

Comment: Also "mi esposa sale de cuentas el 4 de junio"

Comment: @Laura I completely forgot about that :)

Comment: Just to add some cultural context. In Mexico is very common that people say "Mi esposa se alivia el cuatro de junio." "Aliviarse" means "to get well" as in getting well from an illness. That being said is extremely common but, personally, I think that is very wrong because being pregnant is not an illness.

Comment: @JoulSauron, in "Lo esperamos..." is the "lo" referring to the birth or the baby?  In other words, if you're expecting a girl, would it change to "La esperamos..."?

Comment: @Rachel good question, it's referred to the child. If it's a girl and it's already known by the parents, then it is said "la esperamos". However, usually people think of "el bebé" (the baby) regardless being a boy or a girl, so it's more common "lo esperamos".

Comment: I would add: "Mi esposa da a luz ..."

Comment: @Icarus "dar a luz" se utiliza cuando ya ha nacido. En este caso la pregunta es sobre cuándo se estima que nacerá.

Comment: @JoulSauron qué tal: "Mi esposa da a luz el 20 de Junio"? o "Mi esposa da a luz dentro de dos semanas"? No entiendo por qué dices que sólo se utiliza cuando ya ha nacido el bebé.

Comment: @Icarus porque entonces usas el futuro, y el se refiere a una expresión concreta del inglés. "Dar a luz" es "parir" y "salir de cuentas" es "cuando debería parir". El matiz es distinto, y él está preguntando exactamente por lo segundo.

Comment: @JoulSauron por lo menos en cuba y colombia se usa regularmente, Cuando va a dar a luz tu esposa? y tu respondes: - deberia o va a dar a luz para tal fecha, el que si nunca habia escuchado es el de salir de cuentas, eso si me suena a una traduccion literal del due date del ingles, que no se si se usa en otros paises.