# ¿Qué significa el título "Todo un Parto"?

Tags: expresiones, modismos, significado, título

¿Qué significa "Todo un Parto", que es el nombre de una película?

> ***Due Date*** (**Salidos De Cuentas** en España y **Todo Un Parto** en Hispanoamérica) es una película cómica estadounidense estrenada el 5 de noviembre de 2010, dirigida por Todd Phillips y escrita por Alan R. Cohen y Alan Freedland. Protagonizada por Robert Downey Jr. y Zach Galifianakis.
>
> Fuente: [wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Due_Date)

¿Qué significa "Todo un parto"?

Answer (score 4):

Como suele ocurrir con los títulos de películas, hay un juego de palabras destinado a atraer la atención de los potenciales espectadores.

"parto" se refiere al momento de dar a luz a un bebé, lo que está en consonancia con el título original, "due date", que se refiere a la fecha prevista de parto.

Al mismo tiempo, la expresión "(fue) todo un parto" o "(fue) un parto" describe una situación difícil. "todo" refuerza esta idea. Así, "todo un parto" hace alusión al nacimiento del bebé y, al mismo tiempo, a las adversidades o contrariedades que rodearon al hecho.

Answer (score 3):

Es una especie de juego de palabras. "Due date" en inglés es la fecha de "[salir de cuentas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13378/5481)" que es cuando se estima o espera que va a nacer el bebé.

Los partos ([dar a luz](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20723/5481)), por supuesto, no son fáciles y la expresión que algo es "un parto" implica que algo es difícil. Es como si te dijeran "es como ir al dentista": Una experiencia ardua y no muy agradable.

La traducción mantiene la relación con el tema del nacimiento de un bebé y lo que conlleva. Sin haber visto la película ni leer la descripción, entiendo que es es una de esas comedias alrededor de las peripecias, problemas y enredos de los protagonistas en relación a todos los preparativos de la llegada del bebé.

Podrías hacer el juego de palabras entonces de que

> Prepararse para el parto es... *todo un parto*.

(Prepararse para el parto es una tarea larga, ardua, difícil, etc.)

Comment: Relacionado: [How should I discuss my wife's due date?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2208/5481)